# Magento 2 - How to add facebook recent posts into my custom phtml page

Tags: api, magento2.4.1, facebook

I want to show recent Facebook posts into my custom phtml file, how to include them on Magento website?

Comment: are you looking for something like http://jsfiddle.net/tLkpvhnb/ ?

Comment: Yes, but i want to display only posts not extra content and horizontal post slider.